# Delphi XE2 starter - what are my options for database access

Tags: delphi

I bought Delphi XE2 Starter edition because I can't really afford the other versions and didn't really read the full spec sheet.

Now I find that my old Delphi 7 programs which use TAdoConnection, won't compile as ADO DB is not included in the Starter Edition (although I seem to recall downloading it seperately for Delphi 7).

I would strongly prefer to Download ADOB and install it - can I somehow?

If not, what are my free and low prices options for database access? Preferably ODBC, although I might be able to live with MySql only.

---

Update: I intend to purchaser AnyDac/UniDac/MyDac (the choice of which will be another question).

However, I couldn't help but notice that my own generic collection of functions is all in a single unit and if I link that unit's DCU with the XE2 starter edition, voila! I have d/b access in the Delphi XE2 starter edition.

Comment: You paid 199.00 euro without reading the spec sheet? Nice!

Comment: We use freeware DeerSoft ADO components for Delphi 5 since we did not get Enterprise version. Source is included, so maybe some updating will get it to work with XE2. http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=569

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that, @Johan. That question asked how to get ADODB for Delphi XE2, and the answer is to buy a version that includes it. This question asks what to use instead.

Comment: +1 (and I wish it could be more) for stating that so clearly. Thanks, Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some commercial data access packages you can get or perhaps this OpenSource one may work for you:  http://www.productivity.org/projects/tmysql/

Some commercial options for Delphi and MySQL (and there is support for other databases as well):

http://www.devart.com/mydac/

http://www.microolap.com/products/connectivity/mysqldac/

http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/

Comment: Thanks, Daniel,  I will purchase either AnyDay/UniDac/MyDac - the choice of which will be the subject of another question

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't download additional modules for Starter Edition (even for pay) from Embarcadero, you have to use some thirdparty solution which doesn't depend on `TDataSet` (as AFAIK it isn't included in Starter Edition). Some options are

- [KADAO](http://kadao.dir.bg/) - if you want to stick with ADO;
- [ZeosLib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/) - open source, supports MySQL, PostgreSQL, Interbase, Firebird, MS SQL, Sybase, Oracle and SQLite;
- [UIB](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=5) for Interbase and Firebird;

Answer (score 1):

If you have the starter edition, you can use ZEOS access components.
You can download the XE2 package from SVN.
That's a bit fiddly, so in case you are unfamiliar with SVN here's a step by step.

1. Download a SVN client: http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html
2. Create a new folder to put the ZEOS components in; I use `c:\borland\ZEOS`
3. Right-click, and choose `Tortoise SVN` from the menu, then `checkout` or `add`.
4. copy paste the following url: https://zeoslib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/zeoslib/branches/testing
5. There's a minor bug in the sourcecode that prevents it from compiling, see this answer how to fix that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8389516/650492
6. As per usual you'll have add the directories the source code resides in to the search path, see: [How to correctly set "Directories/Conditionals" and "Library" path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658824/how-to-correctly-set-directories-conditionals-and-library-path)